# Event handler vs. event receiver

Tags: event-handlers

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms453149.aspx says

To create the event handler
1. Start Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.
2. On the File menu, point to New, and then click Project.
3. In Project Types, under Visual Basic or C#, select Event Receiver.
...

So wait, is there a difference between an event receiver and an event handler?  Or is it just that what is commonly referred to as an event handler in most environments is for some reason called an event receiver in SharePoint?

For example in this link - http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2009/03/12/develop-and-deploy-a-sharepoint-event-receiver-from-the-scratch/ - the author uses "event handler" throughout, except when referencing the SharePoint class names.  Googling for "event receiver" turns up mostly SharePoint references, with a few Microsoft Office hits here and there.

If anyone has the definitive word on this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Documentation refers to "event handlers" but code uses "event receivers". We have more tags using the "event handlers" term here, therefore I've made "event receiver" a synonym of [tag:event-handlers] on this site.

Answer (score 8):

Both mean the same; handle the Event or receive the event.

Answer (score 8):

Going back to WSS2/SP2003 it was Event Handler.  With WSS3/SP2007 it changed to Event Receiver...there is even a setting on the Web App in CA that let's you enable/disable support for backwards-compatible event handling.

In the context of 2010, "event handler" or "event receiver" is one in the same.

Answer (score 4):

An *Event Receiver* is managed code that responds to SharePoint Foundation events whenever specific triggering actions occur - which is same as *Event Handler*.

The term "*Event Receiver*" is specific to context of SharePoint where as "*Event handler*" is a general term used for any subroutine that handles inputs received in a program.
*Event handlers* are a central concept in event-driven programming.

Comment: In addition to this, Event Handlers are usually asynchronous delegated blocks of code, whereas SharePoint Event Receivers can be asynchronous or synchronous.

Comment: Event handlers are usually synchronous, no?

Comment: An 'Event handler' in context of SharePoint is named as 'Event Receiver'-both are same. Event Handler\Receiver can be asynchronous or synchronous.

Comment: Imagine you have a PDF file on your desktop, It can be represented by a 'File' object.When you upload the same file to a document library in SharePoint, It becomes 'SPFile'. Still that file remains a file!...only attached contextual information differs.Same applies to 'Event Receiver' and 'Event handler'